# Delete/Create in-place (without redirect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails question. I'm building a site where posts have likes, both posts and likes are their own model. A user can only like a post once, and once they like it the like button becomes an "unlike" button, that deletes the like.

I'm trying to create an experience in which the user can like, or unlike a post - and will not be redirected, but the like will update. With my limited rails knowledge, this isn't an easy task. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my `/likes/_likes.html.erb` template partial with the like/unlike button:

<% liked = @post.likes.find { |like| like.user_id == current_user.id} %>

```
<div class="likes">
    <% if liked %>
      <%= button_to 'Unlike', post_like_path(@post, liked), method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= button_to 'Like', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post %>
    <% end %>
    <%= @post.likes.count %><%= (@post.likes.count) == 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'%>
</div>
```

Here is my Like controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post
    before_action :find_like, only: [:destroy]

    def create
        if (!already_liked?)
            @post.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
        end
    end

    def destroy
        if (already_liked?)
            @like.destroy
        end
    end

    private

    def already_liked?
        Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id:
        params[:post_id]).exists?
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def find_like
       @like = @post.likes.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Here is one of the views in which the _likes partial shows up (although the issue persists everywhere it appears):

```
<div class="post-display">
    <% if @post.title %>
        <h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
    <% end %>
    <% if @post.user %>
        Post by <%= @post.user.email %>
    <% end %>
    <% if @post.price %>
        <p>$<%= sprintf "%.2f", @post.price %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if @post.description %>
        <p><%= @post.description %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if @post.image.present? %>
        <%= image_tag @post.image.variant(:small) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= render 'likes/likes' %>
</div>

<% if current_user == @post.user %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>

    <%= button_to "Delete", @post, method: :delete %>
<% end %>

<% if @post.comments.count > 0 %>
    <div class="post-comments">
        <h2 class="post-comments-headline">Comments</h2>
        <%= render @post.comments %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

If you don't have an answer to my question, but have an idea on how to improve my code - let me know either way! I'm trying to learn here...

Thank you,

Jill

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the page to refresh but update reactively?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the original comment, so I'll try again, what I remember of it.

I haven't worked with Rails 7 yet, so I don't have a clear answer for you about how to update the buttons without re-rendering the whole page, but I think you will want to take a look at [Hotwire](https://hotwired.dev/), and Turbo and Stimulus thereof. The Rails guide [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) should get you started on that, too.

Comment: Other advice I have based on the code you posted: you should make database queries in the controller and not in the views. Any time you are calling `@post.likes`, `@post.likes.count`, `@post.user`, `@post.user.image`, `@post.image.variant(:small)`, `@post.comments.count`, or similar, you are making a database query, and you want to minimize the number of them per page.

Also, you will want to eager load your likes, user, image, and comments when you query your posts to avoid the infamous and common N+1 queries problem; see https://pawelurbanek.com/rails-n-1-queries, for example.

Comment: Often information such as how money is rendered, or the logic for whether to show a button and what text in it in each case, is encapsulated in a helper method to remove logic from views (templates), and make the logic testable.

Comment: are you open to using rails-7 turbo/stimulus?

Comment: it's not possible if without Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using *rails 7*, rendering `turbo_stream` in response to "like" and "unlike" buttons will update the page without refreshing.

```rb
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  # NOTE: i'm using singular `resource`, since there is no need to have `id`
  #       for each like.
  resource :like, only: [:destroy, :create]
end
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource*

```rb
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes

  def liked_by? user
    likes.where(user: user).exists?
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/like.rb
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  # NOTE: avoid double likes. 
  validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :post, message: "already liked this post"

  # TODO: create a unique index migration, to really avoid double likes. 
  #       `add_index :likes, [:post_id, :user_id], unique: true`
end
```

I've simplified `LikesController` a bit. No need for *before_action* filters:

```rb
# app/controllers/likes_controller.rb
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  # POST /posts/:post_id/like
  def create
    # NOTE: uniqueness validation in `Like` model will prevent creating dup likes.
    post.likes.create(user: current_user)

    # you can access `like` error if you want to show it:
    # like = post.likes.create(user: current_user)
    # like.errors.full_messages

    # NOTE: that's it, now we render `likes` partial inside a `turbo_stream`
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(
      helpers.dom_id(post, :like), # this is the target div `id` that will be replaced
      partial: "posts/likes",      # with `likes` partial.
      locals: { post: post }
    )
  end

  # DELETE /posts/:post_id/like
  def destroy
    # NOTE: this will work regardless if there are any likes or not.
    post.likes.where(user: current_user).destroy_all

    # NOTE: alternatively, we can render the same `turbo_stream` as above 
    #       in a template `likes/likes.turbo_stream.erb`:
    render :likes
  end

  private

  def post
    @post ||= Post.find params[:post_id]
  end
end
```

```html
<!-- app/views/posts/_likes.html.erb -->

<!-- `dom_id` helps us generate a uniq id: "like_post_1" -->
<div id="<%= dom_id(post, :like) %>">

  <!-- yes, there is a rails helper for this -->
  <%= pluralize post.likes.count, "like" %>

  <% if post.liked_by? current_user %>
    <%= button_to "Unlike", post_like_path(post), method: :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= button_to "Like", post_like_path(post) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This `turbo_stream` is the same as in `create` action:

```html
<!-- app/views/likes/likes.turbo_stream.erb -->
<%= turbo_stream.replace dom_id(@post, :like) do %>
  <%= render "posts/likes", post: @post %>
<% end %>
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> views file where likes partial render

```
<div id='post_likes'>
  <%= render 'likes/likes' %>
</div>
```

> /likes/_likes.html.erb

```
<div class="likes">
    <% if liked %>
      <%= button_to 'Unlike', post_like_path(@post, liked), method: :delete, remote: true %>
    <% else %>
      <%= button_to 'Like', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
    <%= @post.likes.count %><%= pluralize(@post.likes.count, 'Like') %>
</div>
```

> views/likes/create.js.erb

```
$('#post_likes').html('<%= render 'likes/likes' %>');
```

> views/likes/destroy.js.erb

```
$('#post_likes').html('<%= render 'likes/likes' %>');
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue - still redirected after clicking like/unlike.

Comment: For Ritesh solution you need to install rails ujs https://www.npmjs.com/package/rails-ujs. But is better try to use turbo-rails for that (https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/UPGRADING.md)